# UC browser on force download file type is unknown

Tags: php, video, browser

I got stuck in a very unusual problem. I am using php force download for downloading video files in my website which works fine in most browsers such as chrome firefox IE used in pc. But UC browser on my windows mobile shows the file extension as unknown(eg: if file is video1.mp4 , my downloaded file is video1.unknown).
Any help welcome.

```
if(file_exists($myfile))
{
    // Add bellow code for mime type
$temp = explode(".",$myfile);
$ext = strtolower(end($temp));
$mime_types = array(

        // video
        '3gp' => 'video/3gpp',
        '3g2' => 'video/3g2',
        'avi' => 'video/avi',
        'mp4' => 'video/mp4',
        'asf' => 'video/asf',
        'mov' => 'video/quicktime',
    );
if (array_key_exists($ext, $mime_types)){
   $mm_type=$mime_types[$ext];
}else{
   $mm_type="application/octet-stream";
}
$fname=str_replace(" ","_",$result->TITLE);
//header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: public");

header("Content-Type: ".$mm_type);

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$fname);
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($myfile));
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($myfile);
} 
else
{
    echo "unable to download";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding file extension with the filename solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

the UC Browser you installed was for phone, not for PC.

you can try its PC version which was launched last year.

here's the link: http://pc.ucweb.com/?from=ghx0005

Comment: please post your own answer and then reference.